# Errors but correct pdf | Biblatex with Biber, Glossaries and Babel

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, glossaries, babel, biber

I'm tring to use Biber and Glossaries also with different languages in a document. Actually, everything is working well, but it outputs some errors which are more warnings because the correct PDF is also produced.
Nevertheless, the errors are irritating me in my development environment Eclipse with Texlipse Plugin.

#### Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{superBib.bib}

@book{bohm_sys,
    title = {System-Entwicklung in der Wirtschaftsinformatik},
    isbn = {978-3-7281-2762-4},
    pagetotal = {702},
    publisher = {vdf Hochschulverlag {AG}},
    author = {Böhm, Rolf},
    date = {2002},
    langid = {german},
    keywords = {Systemdenken}
}

@online{james_scrum_2012,
    title = {Scrum Reference Card},
    url = {http://scrumreferencecard.com/ScrumReferenceCard.pdf},
    titleaddon = {Scrum Reference Card},
    type = {Knowledge},
    author = {James, Michael},
    date = {2012},
    keywords = {{SCRUM}}
}

\end{filecontents*}

%% BIBER BibLatex  
 \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=ynt,  natbib=true]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{superBib.bib}

\usepackage[ngerman,polish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % 
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist,section]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    %% Set some Acronyms and Glossary Entries
    \newacronym{acr:ram}{RAM}{Random-access memory}
    \newacronym{acr:csv}{CSV}{Comma-separated values}
    \newglossaryentry{glo:btrat}{name={bitrate},description={It effects the file-size and quality of a video}}
    \newglossaryentry{glo:dynamicweb}{name={dynamic website},description={server generated code}}
    \newglossaryentry{glo:staticweb}{name={static website},description={hard coded content, server just delivers the document}}

    %% Print Acronym and Glossary
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=list, title=List of Abbreviations, toctitle=List of Abbreviations]
    \glsaddall[types=main]      %added all defined Glossentries 
    \printglossary[type=main,style=altlist, title=Glossary, toctitle=Glossary]

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]

    \section{Cites}
        Hello \citet{james_scrum_2012} and another \parencite{bohm_sys}    

    \section{Acr and Glo}

%    Here we use \gls{acr:ram} and followed by a GlossaryEntry: \gls{glo:btrat}

    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    Hallo Welt

\end{document}
```

#### Some Error Message:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                 \bbl@loaded
l.47 \begin{document}


! Extra \endcsname.
\cslet ...>\expandafter \let \csname #1\endcsname
                                                  #2
l.47 \begin{document}

! Extra \endcsname.
\blx@maplang ...d \csname abx@extras@#2\endcsname
                                                  \expandafter \noexpand \cs...
l.47 \begin{document}


! Extra \endcsname.
\blx@maplang ... \csname abx@strings@#2\endcsname
                                              }\csxappto {noextras#1}{\n...
l.47 \begin{document}


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\.tex" File ignored)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \bbl@loaded
l.47 \begin{document}
```

If you uncomment everything that belongs to glossaries one warning remain

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...docsvlist \expandafter {\bbl@loaded
                                    }\ifboolexpr { not test {\...
l.47 \begin{document}
```

Is it possible that the Babel package is the culprit?

I'm using a small batch file to produce the output - the general steps are:

> pdflatex
>
> makeindex -q -s *.ist -t *.alg -o *.acr *.acn
>
> makeindex -q -s *.ist -t *.glg -o *.gls *.glo
>
> biber
>
> pdflatex
>
> pdflatex

### Edit: Solution is to update

The `babel` version was to old - after using the **MikTeX Update Manager** and not the *Package Manager* everything is fine now!

Comment: I have no problem with this file / command sequence. Are you sure your `biblatex` and `biber` versions match? See Table 1 in the Biber manual for the compatibility matrix if you are unsure.

Comment: @jon I used \listfiles to get the version numbers: `biblatex v3.2` and `biber v2.3` so that matches from the compatibility matrix. `glossaries.sty    2015/03/16 v4.15 (NLCT)` and    `babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package`
 `bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration` and to complete this comment: `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`

Comment: Your `babel` version is too old for your modern version of `biblatex` and Biber. The command `\bbl@loaded` is quite recent and tells `biblatex` which languages were used. Update MikTeX in both User and Admin mode, see [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864).

Comment: This might be something different, but I had many typeset problems.Try encoding your umlauts into `{\"u}` `{\"o}` and `{\"a}`. This led to a few errors in my case earlier. A nice combination btw is `biblatex` with `biber` for your literature and `acro` for your acronyms.

Comment: @Eric: In a modern system with biblatex there is really no need to use \"u.

Comment: @moewe Bääm! it's true babel looked for me also very old - I looked in the packet manager for new updates but didn't find anything! But there is also the **MikTeX Update Manager** to handle this! _Everything is working now!_   It seems that I had [this issue here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2316/)

Comment: Precisely, the Update manager is for updates, the Package Manager doesn't normally do updates for you. Can we close this question as "solved by an update"?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good to know! I've also updated my biblatex. :D

Comment: @moewe Sure, 'solved by update'!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an update (see comment above).