# Undefined control sequence. \begin{document} Existing Document wont compile anymore

Tags: errors

I experience that my allways working Latex Template wont work anymore. I have not changed anything since the last time i was using it but for some reason it wont compile anymore.
Error Message is:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...docsvlist \expandafter {\bbl@loaded
}\ifboolexpr { not test {\...
l.423 \begin{document}
```

I have tried to create a Basic sample with all the settings made in the Preamble:

```
    \newif\ifprint
\printtrue % Druckversion (Standard)
%\printfalse % Screenversion

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Dokumentenklasse --------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,               % Papierformat
    twoside=true,           % beidseitig bedruckt
    fontsize=12pt,          % Schriftgröße
    titlepage=true,         % Titelseite
    listof=totoc,           % Tabellen-/Abb.verzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
    bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
    listof=left,            % Tabellen-/Abb.verzeichnis ohne Einzug, hängend
    open=right,             % Kapitel rechts beginnen
    cleardoublepage=plain,  % pagestyle für leere Seite vor Kapitel
    headsepline=true,       % Header mit Linie abtrennen
    footsepline=false,      % Footer nicht mit Linie abtrennen
    captions=tableheading,  % Abstände anpassen, für Captions oberhalb von Tab.
    numbers=noendperiod,    % keine Punkte am Ende von Kapitel-/Anhangnummern
    parskip=half-,          % halber Zeilenabstand zwischen Absätzen
    headings=normal         % Überschriften "normaler" Größe
]{scrbook}[2008/11/03] % Version 3.00 wurde 2008-11-03 veröffentlicht



\usepackage{scrhack}
\KOMAoptions{hyperref=false}




%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Schrifttyp --------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{lmodern}


\lccode`\-=`\-
\defaulthyphenchar=127 


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Satzspiegelberechnung ---------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

% Mit der if-Abfrage \ifprint wird zwischen Druck- und Screenversion
% umgeschaltet!
\ifprint % Druck: Ränder Doppelseite im Verhältnis 1:1:1, mit Bindekorrektur
  \geometry{%
    includehead=true, % wg. fancyhdr-Formatierung zählt Head optisch zum Text
    hmarginratio=1:2, % Rand innen:außen (für Doppelseite ergibt sich: 1:1:1)
    vmarginratio=3:5, % Rand oben:unten (Standard: typearea 1:2, geometry 2:3)
    textwidth=170mm,  % Breite der Textfläche (ohne Randnotizen)
    textheight=230mm, % Höhe der Textfläche (ohne Header)
    headheight=20pt,  % Header größer gegen overfull vboxes (Standard: 12pt)
    footskip=15mm,    % Abstand Baseline des Footer zum Textkörper
    bindingoffset=6mm % Bindekorrektur BCOR
  }%
\else % Screen: horizontal zentriert, ohne Bindekorrektur
  \geometry{%
    includehead=true, % wg. fancyhdr-Formatierung zählt Head optisch zum Text
    hmarginratio=1:1, % Rand innen:außen (PDF: Textkörper zentrieren!)
    vmarginratio=3:5, % Rand oben:unten (Standard: typearea 1:2, geometry 2:3)
    textwidth=170mm,  % Breite der Textfläche (ohne Randnotizen)
    textheight=230mm, % Höhe der Textfläche (ohne Header)
    headheight=20pt,  % Header größer gegen overfull vboxes (Standard: 12pt)
    footskip=15mm,    % Abstand Baseline des Footer zum Textkörper
    bindingoffset=0mm % Bindekorrektur BCOR
  }%
\fi



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Absatzlayout ------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{setspace}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\tolerance 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em

\hbadness 1414


\hfuzz 0.3pt
\vfuzz 0.3pt


\raggedbottom
%\flushbottom



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Abschnittslayout (chapter, sections, paragraphs) ------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % subsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % subsection


\newcommand{\dottedsection}[1]{#1.} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
\@startsection%
  {paragraph}%
  {4}%
  {\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph\dottedsection}%
}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saved@chapter}{}
\let\saved@chapter\chapter

\newcommand*{\my@chapter}[2][]{%
  \bookmarksetup{bold=true}%
  \saved@chapter[#1]{#2}%
  \bookmarksetup{bold=false}%
}

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \@ifstar{\saved@chapter*}{\@dblarg\my@chapter}%
}
\makeatother


\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
\vspace*{\baselineskip} % KOMA-Script-Standard: 2.3\baselineskip
}




%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Literaturverzeichnis ----------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}


\usepackage[%
% backend=biber,     % Biber als Backend bevorzugt, aber aus Gründen der
                    % Einfachheit wird für die Vorlage bibtex verwendet, da die
                    % LaTeX-Editoren dieses i.d.R. standardmäßig integriert haben.
  backend=bibtex8,  % bibtex8 kümmert sich ausschließlich um die Sortierung
  style=alphabetic, % Label: [Pe13]
 % style=numeric,    % Label: [1]
  sortcase=false,   % case-insensitive sorting
  maxnames=3,       % Namenslisten von mehr als maxname werden auf minnames gekürzt
  minnames=2,       % Namenslisten von mehr als maxname werden auf minnames gekürzt
  sorting=anyt      % sort: alphabetic label, name, year, title
]{biblatex}

% Autoren: Nachname, Vorname
% default: used by numeric and alphabetic style
% sortname: used by authoryear, authortitle, and verbose style
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Name mit ';' trennen, da ',' nun Nachname und Vornamen trennt
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Nachnamen mit Kapitälchen (small caps) formatieren
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}

% <authors>: <title>
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

% Statt u.a. soll et al. auch im Deutschen abgekürzt werden
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}} 



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Mathematisches ----------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{icomma}


\usepackage[sumlimits,intlimits]{amsmath}




%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Rechtschreibung, Silbentrennung -----------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}





%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Einheiten ---------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{sistyle}     % Nummernformatierung

% Produktzeichen \SI{5e2}{N} wird zu: $5 \cdot 10^2\,\mathrm{N}$
\SIproductsign{\cdot} 

% Dezimaltrennzeichen: Komma
\SIdecimalsign{,}






%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Längen ------------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{calc}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Tabellen/Arrays ---------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{.3em} % trim-Länge für \cmidrule, Standard: .5em




%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Listen, Aufzählungen ----------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Floats ------------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\setcounter{topnumber}{3}     % Standard: 2
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}  % Standard: 1
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}   % Standard: 3


% Mindestanteil zur Erzeugung einer float-page (nur floats auf einer Seite)
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}  % Standard: 0.5

% Mindestanteil von Text, sonst wird die Seite zur float-page
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}       % Standard: 0.2

% Maximalanteil, den floats am Seitenanfang einer Seite einnehmen dürfen.
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}        % Standard: 0.7

% Maximalanteil, den floats am Seitenende einer Seite einnehmen dürfen.
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7}     % Standard: 0.3

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{htbp}%
\renewcommand{\fps@table}{htbp}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{float}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Farben und Grafiken -----------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[update]{epstopdf}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Bildunterschriften/Tabellenüberschriften --------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{caption}[2008/08/24]

\captionsetup{                  % globale Option für caption und subcaption
  font=normalsize,              % Schrift der Caption (Label+Text)
  format=hang,                  % Formatierung der Caption
  justification=RaggedRight,    % linksbündig bei mehreren caption-Zeilen
  singlelinecheck=true,         % true: einzelne Linie zentriert!
  labelfont=bf,                 % Schrift des Labels
  textfont=rm,                  % Schrift des Textes
  position=bottom               % Normale Caption unter dem Float
}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[sub]{         % subcaption Optionen
  font=small,               % Schrift der Caption (Label+Text)
  labelfont=rm,             % Schrift des Labels
  textfont=rm,              % Schrift des Textes
  skip=10pt,                % Abstand Caption <> Subfigure
  %nearskip=0pt,             % Abstand Caption <> Folgetext (wenn Caption unten)
  labelformat=brace         % Einzelne Klammer rechts: a)
}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- PDF-bezogene Pakete -----------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\definecolor{seclinks}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}  % blau, Verweise auf Abschnitte, Floats
\definecolor{citelinks}{rgb}{0,0.5,0} % grün, Verweise auf Quellen/Literatur
\definecolor{urllinks}{rgb}{0,0,0}    % schwarz, Verweise auf externe URLs


\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  %hyperfootnotes=true,          % footnote verlinken zum footnotetext
  plainpages=false,             % true > Erzwingt arabische (1,2,...) Zahlen
  linktocpage=false,            % Seitenzahlen im Inhaltsverz. verlinkt
  unicode=true,                 % Unicode-Zeichen in Bookmarks, s.u.
  breaklinks=true               % Umbrüche in Links erlaubt
}

\ifprint % Druckversion
  \hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=false,            % Links werden umrandet dargestellt
    pdfborder=0 0 0,             % Umrandung wird deaktiviert
    pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight % Doppelseite, ungerade Seiten rechts
  }
\else % Screenversion
  \hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,             % Links werden farblich dargestellt
    linkcolor=seclinks,          % "normal internal links" > Farbdefinition s.o.
    citecolor=citelinks,         % "bibliographical cites" > Farbdefinition s.o.
    urlcolor=urllinks,           % URLs > Farbdefinition s.o.
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn      % eine Seite, kontinuierliches Scrollen
  }
\fi


\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{%
  open=true,        % Bookmark-Baumstruktur ausgeklappt
  openlevel=1,      % Anzahl der Ebenen, die ausgeklappt werden
  numbered=true     % Nummerierung d. Bookmarks mit Nummern
}

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\renewcommand{\hypcapspace}{\baselineskip} % Zusätzliche Verschiebung nach oben


\usepackage{pdfpages}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Diverse Einstellungen und Pakete ----------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\usepackage{ifthen}


\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{xspace}


\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%---- Dokumentenanfang --------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try removing the `.aux` file?

Comment: Your babel version is imho too old for biblatex. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292269/errors-but-correct-pdf-biblatex-with-biber-glossaries-and-babel

Comment: Your MWE is far away to be minimal. Please reduce it until it still will show your problem. In this process probably you will find cause of your trouble.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but documentclass must be the first line in the document. Is there any difference if you put the newif after documentclass?

Comment: Is this a template provided by your university?

Comment: As Ulrike says, this looks as though your version of `babel` is too old. Update (all!) your packages, on MikTeX use the 'MikTeX Update' tool in *both* User *and* Admin mode, with TeX live run `tlmgr`.