# Error using glossaries and babel

Tags: biblatex, glossaries, babel, urls

I'm writing my thesis in LaTeX. Please see my MWE below.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[alldates=short,style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This code repeatedly gives

> ```
> "Error: missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{document}" 
> "Error: extra \endcsname. \begin{document}".
> ```

### Background:

I recently realised that my online references were displaying the date accessed in the US format (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy). I want them in UK format (dd/mm/yyyy), so I found [this question](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23212) which suggested I should load `babel` with the `british` option - I had a look at the package documentation and decided to use `UKenglish`.

This fixed my `urldate` problem, but gave me `"Error: missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{document}"` and `"Error: extra \endcsname. \begin{document}"` over and over again.

I have also tried loading `biblatex` first, followed by `glossaries`, then `babel`. This gives me `"Error: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}"`.

The error goes away when I get rid of `glossaries` or `babel`. Is there an incompatibility between the two packages that I don't know about? Is there a way I could solve my `urldate` problem without using `babel`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for providing the MWE. Are you sure it is an example though? On my computer, running the above example gives no errors.

Comment: One thing to check: do you have any files named `book`, `biblatex`, `babel` or `glossaries` in your current directory (or somewhere TeX may be finding it)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'll edit a part of your question to accommodate for that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR that's odd, I get the error when I run the MWE I provided. there aren't any strange files in my directory, and I'm not sure where else TeX might be getting them from...

Comment: @gldraper That's strange. You can try providing the entire output leading up to the error message(s), and maybe also the `.log` file (which will contain similar output).

Comment: You can find the `.log` file [here](https://pastebin.com/DPCjTgcx). Errors start at line 577.

Comment: Searching for that error message (`! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \bbl@loaded
l.9 \begin{document}
`) leads to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292269/errors-but-correct-pdf-biblatex-with-biber-glossaries-and-babel), which was solved by updating `babel`. Might that work for you too?

Comment: Your babel dates back to 2008, while `biblatex` is up to date. Make in update in both Admin an User mode. `babel` is installed in Admin mode. But it is not a bad idea to also update in User mode. Please run each of the updaters twice.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR @moewe Thanks for the help. Updating `babel` in Admin mode fixed my issue!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a horribly outdated version of `babel`. Updating fixed the problem.